# Что такое указатель?

Tags: указатели, любой-язык

Что это такое? Как с ним работать?

Answer (score 5):

Указатель - это участок памяти, указывающий на какой-то другой ее участок.

Например:

```
int a = 5;  
int *b = &a;  
(*b)++;  
printf("%d", a);  
/* Вывод: "6" */
```

Т.е. меняется значение не `b`, а переменной `a`.

Comment: адрес памяти

Answer (score 0):

Указатель (поинтер, англ. pointer) — переменная, диапазон значений которой состоит из адресов ячеек памяти и специального значения — нулевого адреса. Значение нулевого адреса не является реальным адресом и используется только для обозначения того, что указатель в данный момент не может использоваться для обращения ни к какой ячейке памяти.

[http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Указатель (тип данных)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85))